# Get list of files from different computer running Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ls

I have 2 Ubuntu machines `XX.XXX.XX.X and YY.YYY.YY.Y`. Now I logged into the 1st machine. I want to know the list of files in a specific folder in the 2nd machine. If my system is the same one, then I can just use `ls`, but for the current situation, how can I get the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have OpenSSH server enabled on remote machines, just type in the local console:

> ssh user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "ls -l "

You can also use command diff, but first you must mount a folder using the sshfs filesystem:

> sudo sshfs -o allow_other,defer_permissions user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/ /mnt/folder1

After this, execute the diff command as comparing two folder on your local machine.

Comment: Is there any way to pass a pattern string to match with the file names? If file name matches with this pattern then only that name to be returned

Answer (score 0):

**Possible 1 :-** If you just want to see list of files -  login into the other system with following command- go to specified path - type command 'ls'.

connect with port

```
ssh root@<ip-address> -p <port>
```

connect without port

```
ssh root@<ip-address>
```

**Possible 2 :-** write script to get list of file names.

**Possible 3 :-** If you just ignore the size of the folder, then use open ssh command, get all files into local system.

```
sudo scp -r  root@<ip-address>:/subfolder/subfolder1/folder/ .
```